# Error 401 - Unauthorized in NTLM authentication WSDL SOAP parsing Android - NTLM

Tags: java, android, dynamics-crm-2011, ntlm, android-ksoap2

I am trying to parse the Windows CRM web-service for Android.
For that I have to authenticate. For that I used NTLM but I am new for both CRM and NTLM in Java.

I am Confused which parameter I have to pass in credential mention below:
what I have to take in workstation and in domain.

Please give some example for same kind of soap service URL if any can.

```
NTCredentials mCredentials = new NTCredentials(userName, password, workstation, domain);
```

And also in authscope and credentials.

```
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(authscope, credentials), creds);
```

Comment: Hi @Mihir, are you solved it? I'm developing a new service to do NTLM authentication https://www.nafiux.com/wasp/ if I can help you please let me know